# Shell: Insert line number two lines above matching string into file

Tags: bash

I want to insert text along with the line number to a file where it matches a grep statement.

## Example file

```
-----------------------------
-- Ticket #: 10001
-- Subject: my subject
-- Author: janedoe
-----------------------------

-----------------------------
-- Ticket #: 10002
-- Subject: my subject2
-- Author: janedoe2
-----------------------------
```

So I want to grep for the word "-- Ticket" and add the corresponding line number two lines above that.

## Expected output

```
PROMPT Line 1
-----------------------------
-- Ticket #: 10001
-- Subject: my subject
-- Author: janedoe
-----------------------------

PROMPT Line 8
-----------------------------
-- Ticket #: 10002
-- Subject: my subject2
-- Author: janedoe2
-----------------------------
```

So I'm able to insert random characters but I can't figure out how to get the line number.

```
sed '/-- Ticket/i\
ssssssss
$H
x' < finalfile.txt
```

Comment: Updated ... preferably the new one.

Comment: Gotcha. "How to get the line number" is easy -- that's what the `sed` command `=` will do.

Comment: BTW, is this the only input format you need to deal with? Will the `Ticket` always be **directly**  below the line of dashes?

Comment: That is correct. The format is pretty spot on.

Comment: Why do you need to use `sed`? (Or why do you think it is a good tool for that?

Comment: @hek2mgl I like that it's 3 letters. <sarcasm>

Comment: Ok, that was sarcasm, now the real reason

Comment: @luckytaxi: Just wondering, shouldn't the fist be line number `2` if you have the second one at line number `8`? How can it be line number `1`?

Comment: @Inian, if we read the "expected output" as canonical, that implies that the intended line numbers are that of the `PROMPT` command generated in the output (which is how my answer is written).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk -v RS= '/-- Ticket/{++i; print "PROMPT Line ", i ORS $0 ORS; i+=split($0, a, /\n/)+1}' file

PROMPT Line 1
-----------------------------
-- Ticket #: 10001
-- Subject: my subject
-- Author: janedoe
-----------------------------

PROMPT Line 8
-----------------------------
-- Ticket #: 10002
-- Subject: my subject2
-- Author: janedoe2
-----------------------------
```

- `awk` splits input data using an empty `RS` thus giving us full ticket section in a separate record.
- Using `split` on newline we can count how many lines are there in each section and get our count for `PROMPT Line`

Comment: Thanks, I found an example using `awk` but couldn't quite get it to work. This works great.

Answer (score 1):

Given the format description, there's no need to look specifically for `-- Ticket`; instead, we can look for a line of dashes (constituting a section header) immediately after a line of whitespace.

That's easier, because it reduces the amount of backtracking needed, and thus avoids a need to buffer content.

```
#!/bin/bash

lineno=0                                        # track our line number
in_section=0                                    # track whether we're already in a section
section_header='-----------------------------'

while IFS= read -r line; do                     # read the file line-by-line
  ((++lineno))                                  # increment our counter
  if [[ $line = "" ]]; then                     # if we see an empty line...
    in_section=0                                # ...then we're not in a section
  elif [[ $line = "$section_header" ]]; then    # if we see a header...
    if (( in_section == 0 )); then              # ...and we're not in a section already
      echo "PROMPT Line $lineno"                # ...then write a section header
      ((++lineno))                              # ...increment our lineno for that header
      in_section=1                              # ...and don't process the header on exit
    fi
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$line"                         # finally, write our line to output
done
```

See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a discussion of reading a file line-by-line in this manner.

Comment: Just a side-note, teaching OPs how to write programs in bash which they could simply write in, let's say, Python is kind of a dead end. Imo bash is not a language for writing applications. I suffered so many times because I had to maintain "software" written in bash by guys who just wanted a "quick" solution.

Comment: @hek2mgl, *shrug*. If people are going to use it for quick-and-dirty things, and I'm going to assert that they *are*, they should be doing it right. Otherwise, we get quick-and-dirty scripts that are buggy and awful. Hence, teaching best-practices bash. If someone's going to be writing a program in a *good* language, they can ask over in that language's tag -- but here, I'm going to be teaching folks to write bash *well*.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...I'll never point someone from the Python or Go or Clojure tags to use bash instead, but at same time, I'm not going to say that bash is unsuited to a task unless it actually *is* (XML parsing w/o external tools, f/e).

Comment: I would've used something besides Bash, BUT this existing script is a long bash script that was written by someone else. I'm not going to rewrite it just because I think Python would be better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's ^^^ what I mean

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...if you're trying to make a point that conflicts in some way with my stated position, then I'm quite missing it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My point is to point OPs in such cases to *good* programming languages. At least as a side-note. In this case it seems that I'm right. The OP seems to be happy with this little help, but the real problem in the company stays the same: hackish bash scripts - written by someone else.

Comment: @hek2mgl - look i would love to use something other than Bash but there's time and effort required to make changes to this script. I'm sure my boss would rather have me work on more important things than modifying a script that barely gets touched. I've only had to touch this script 3 times in the past 4 yrs.